# How can I not execute a GitHub Action when I push a new tag?

Tags: github-actions

I want that my GitHub Action that runs all tests doesn't execute when we push a new tag to the master repository because when we merge new branches we execute this action before, and when we push a tag to create a new release this action executes again.

Right now this action starts with this

```
name: Build and Test
on: push
```

As you see this will execute in every push we would make, and I want to change that this action will execute only when we push commits, no tags. My approximate solution would be this but I am not sure

```
name: Build and Test
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'
    tags-ignore:
      - '*'
```

Answer (score 11):

That should work, but I'd recommend two improvements.

First, use `**` instead of `*` (the edge case here is a branch/tag named `/`).

Second, omit the `tags-ignore` clause. In my testing, Github ignores all tags if you specify `branches` but not `tags` or `tags-ignore`.

```
name: Build and Test
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'
```

Comment: Can confirm this works. This is very helpful if your pipeline builds on each commit sha, the tag build would be purely redundant.

Comment: Just want to highlight that I ended up getting this error unless I explicitly set `--tags-ignore: - '**'`.
i.e. the tag push was rejected even though my workflow only accepted this push-trigger. `on: push: branches: -master`