github actions for a repository and its submodule avoiding infinite loop
I have a github repository A which uses another github repository B as a submodule. Both of which has their own github action.
Repo B can be run independently with its actions, and whenever I run repo A's workflow it will automatically pull the latest version of repo B before proceeding with the rest of its workflow.
Basically what i want is a way to install repo A with clone etc - but to update the submodule to the lastest commit where it's own test were successful. Such that if repo B has 5 new commits all failing, then if i install repo A it will not be those commits.
The github repo B workflow uses some code on a test data set to create some test output files and as such I have made a makefile to make a test checking the md5sums
name: Repo B workflow

on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]
  pull_request:
    branches: ["main"]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash -l {0}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: ["ubuntu-latest"]
        python-version: ["3.11"]

    steps:
      # step 1: checkout repository
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # step 2 use environment.yml dependencies to create conda environment
      - name: Set up miniconda
        uses: conda-incubator/setup-miniconda@v3
        with:
          auto-update-conda: true
          environment-file: environment.yml
          activate-environment: repoB_pipeline
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}

      # step 3
      - name: Run test script
        run: |
          conda activate repoB_pipeline
          make test

      # Step 4: Creating a webhook with repository dispatch
     ...

Once the md5sum has been cleared in step 3, then I am also ('trying'), because repo B is a submodule to set up in step 4 a webhook in the form of a repository dispatch referring to repo A. Such that when I push to repo B it will automatically activate repo A's workflow.
So, after step 3, I would like to somehow create a new step that updates a text file and logs the latest git commit only if step 3 passes. That way, when I clone and install my repo A, I can use git checkout to get the latest successful version of my submodule repo B where I know the tests pass. However, I am not sure how to do this without creating an infinite loop.
To add files within an action I can see you can do as such
- name: Commit Changes
  run: |
    echo "Current commit: $(git rev-parse HEAD)" > commit_info.txt
    git config --local user.name "github-actions[bot]"
    git config --local user.email "github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
    git add commit_info.txt
    git commit -m "Update commit info after successful tests"

However, this would create an infinite loop as it would activate the rest of the repo B workflow again. I can see other suggestions for pushing to a new branch. But are there any ways to simply add this to a main branch or is other branches necessary to solve this particular issue?
If I add it to a different branch of repo B, then as far as I understand, when installing repo A and the submodules, i need to change the submodule repo B branch, get the commit, switch back to the main branch, and then checkout to get the latest commit where the test passed - all to ensure repo A has the latest submodule that worked?
I hope my question makes sense - and I would appreciate any suggestions on how I can avoid any infinite loops while storing the latest successful git commits.
Best regards
Additional code to accommodate the suggestions in the comments below with tags: would this work or create an infinite loop?
on:
  push:
    branches: ["main"]
    tags:
      - "!**"
  pull_request:
    branches: ["main"]
.
.
.
# Step 4: Create tag if test in step 3 passes
      - name: Create tag
        if: ${{ success() }}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          TAG_NAME="RepoB.$('%Y%m%d').${GITHUB_SHA::7}"
          git tag $TAG_NAME
          git push origin $TAG_NAME
          echo "Creating tag: $TAG_NAME"



https://stackoverflow.com/a/66156840/7976758 Add [skip ci] to the commit message: git commit -m "Update commit info" -m "[skip ci]" Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-actions%5D+infinite+loop

Can you not promote a tag, say B_CLEARED, in repo B after step 3 passed? Is it not possible to checkout a submodule at a given tag? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-specify-a-branchtag-when-adding-a-git-submodule/

I have changed the question to accomodate the suggestion with tags, but I want to avoid the possibility of infinite loops, would it be infinite with the changes?
because I can see there exist a lot of different opinions, using secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN, --tags-ignore: ['**'], push tags:-"!**"
https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25615
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68573888/how-can-i-not-execute-a-github-action-when-i-push-a-new-tag
if I do [skip ci] then it wouldn't work with tags, and if I do --tags-ignore: ['**'] it might never run the workflow?
